# Drawing arc with bezier curves

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, geometry, bezier

I am trying to draw an arc using bezier curves. I have learned that you can't draw a perfect circle using bezier curves but you can come close. Unfortunately the math is too complicated and I can't personally figure it out.

I can create the A1 slice below as a triangle, but I can't figure out how to determine the control points. Also if I try drawing a slice out of a circle in the opposite direction, notice how the control points seem to point in the negative direction.

So if I want a slice of a circle with a radius R and I have already computed the anchor points, how can I calculate the position of control point 1 and control point 2???

[image: Example]

Comment: When you talk about bezier curves in iOS, are you referring to `UIBezierPath`? If you are, you can use `bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` to do what you want...

Comment: Or use `addArcWithCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` to add the circular part to an existing path object that you're creating.

Comment: [You must watch this fantastic explanation of how computers draw curves](http://sploid.gizmodo.com/fantastic-explanation-of-how-computers-draw-curves-1641989231). Maybe it helps you to determine how to compute the control points.

Comment: Thanks guys, but I need to calculate the control points manually.

Comment: zisoft, that was the most fantastic explanation of anything I have ever seen. Even idiots like me can understand it.

Comment: The video provided in zisoft's comment actually describes the de Casteljau algorithm in a graphical manner. However, the title of that web article "....how computers draw curves" is slightly misleading because the described algorithm only applies to Bezier curve (not to any kind of curves).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feng Yuan proposed simple method in his book [Windows Graphics Programming](http://www.fengyuan.com/): build an arc with radius 1, centered at OX axis, calculate Bezier approximation for it, and scale, translate and rotate control points for needed arc parameters. Here is my implementation of this method (in Delphi), modified for large arcs. C++ sources can be found somewhere in the Internet, but I hope that the logic is clear.

```
  GenerateBezierArc(200, 200, 150, Pi / 4, 3 * Pi / 2, Pts);
  Canvas.PolyBezier(Pts);
```

result:

[image]

```
type
  TPointArray = array of TPoint;

//calculates array of Bezier control points
//for circle arc with center CX, CY and radius R
procedure GenerateBezierArc(CX, CY, R: Integer;
                            StartAngle, SweepAngle: Double;
                            var Pts: TPointArray);
// C-Pascal translation from Feng Yuan book, with correction of source errors
var
  iCurve, NCurves: Integer;
  i: Integer;
  x0, y0, tx, ty, sn, cs, ASweep, AStart: Double;
  Px, Py: array [0 .. 3] of Double;
begin
  if SweepAngle = 0 then
    Exit;
  // if SweepAngle is too large, divide arc to smaller ones
  NCurves := Ceil(Abs(SweepAngle) / (Pi/2));
  SetLength(Pts, 3 * NCurves + 1);
  ASweep := SweepAngle / NCurves;

  // calculates control points for Bezier approx. of arc with radius=1,
  // circle center at (0,0), middle of arc at (1,0)
  y0 := Sin(ASweep / 2);
  x0 := Cos(ASweep / 2);
  tx := (1 - x0) * 4 / 3;
  ty := y0 - tx * x0 / (y0 + 0.0001);
  Px[0] := x0;
  Py[0] := -y0;
  Px[1] := x0 + tx;
  Py[1] := -ty;
  Px[2] := x0 + tx;
  Py[2] := ty;
  Px[3] := x0;
  Py[3] := y0;

  // rotation and translation of control points
  sn := Sin(StartAngle + ASweep / 2);
  cs := Cos(StartAngle + ASweep / 2);
  Pts[0].X := CX + Round(R * (Px[0] * cs - Py[0] * sn));
  Pts[0].Y := CY + Round(R * (Px[0] * sn + Py[0] * cs));

  for iCurve := 0 to NCurves - 1 do begin
    AStart := StartAngle + ASweep * iCurve;
    sn := Sin(AStart + ASweep / 2);
    cs := Cos(AStart + ASweep / 2);
    for i := 1 to 3 do begin
      Pts[i + iCurve * 3].X := CX + Round(R * (Px[i] * cs - Py[i] * sn));
      Pts[i + iCurve * 3].Y := CY + Round(R * (Px[i] * sn + Py[i] * cs));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Assuming you start this function with a known CX, CY, Px[0], Py[0] and Px[3] Py[3], How do you determine the start angle and the sweep angle?

Comment: @FMaz008 You can calculate angle using arctan2/atan2 function: `an0 := ArcTan2(Py[0]-CY, Px[0]-CX)`

Answer (score 3):

The article referenced by Duncan's post is actually the result for 90 degree circular arc from a journal paper authored by Tor Dokken (the main author) and published in Computer Aided Geometric Design Vol 7 in 1990. It cited two approaches for approximating a 90 degree arc: a standard approach and a better approach. I will list the general formula for the "standard approach" below and leave out the general formula for the "better approach" as it requires a lot of typing:

For a circular arc with angular span A and unit radius, described as C(t) = (cos(t), sin(t)), where t=[0, A], a good cubic Bezier curve approximation can be obtained with the following control points:

P(0) = (1, 0),
P(1) = (1, 0) + L(0,1), 
P(2) = (cosA, sinA) - L (-sinA, cosA), 
P(3) = (cosA, sinA)

where L is a scalar constant depending on A as

L = (4/3)*tan(A/4)

Please note that the cubic Bezier curve approximation obtained this way always interpolates the two end points and the mid-point of the circular arc and the approximation error is always positive, which means the cubic Bezier curve is always "outside" the circular arc.

The maximum radial error (x(t)^2 + y(t)^2 - 1) from this simple formula is

Error_max = (4/27) * ( power(sin(A/4),6)/power(cos(A/4),2) )

When you want to approximate a general circular arc (any angle span and any radius radius) within a certain tolerance, you can use this formula to compute how many segments you need to break the circular arc into and approximate each arc segment with a cubic Bezier curve. Since this cubic Bezier curve will honor the end points and end slopes, all cubic Bezier curves obtained will join smoothly together.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/) gives a set of 4 bezier curves that generates a very close approximation of a circle. It divides the circle into 4 quarters and each curve generates 1/4 of the circle.

I don't know how you'd come up with the control points for an arbitrary arc along a circle. You'd use trig to find the start and end points, but the middle points would be harder.

The conclusion of the article:

The maximum radial drift is 0.019608% with this approximation. This is 28% better than the standard approximation.
Here is the final result:

Figure 4. The Bézier approximation is almost indistinguishable from a circle.
Figure 4 was created using the Bézier curves:
P_0 = (0,1), P_1 = (c,1), P_2 = (1,c), P_3 = (1,0)
P_0 = (1,0), P_1 = (1,-c), P_2 = (c,-1), P_3 = (0,-1)
P_0 = (0,-1), P_1 = (-c,-1), P_3 = (-1,-c), P_4 = (-1,0)
P_0 = (-1,0), P_1 = (-1,c), P_2 = (-c,1), P_3 = (0,1)
with c = 0.551915024494.

That's for a unit circle (a circle on the origin with a radius of 1) You'd need to scale it for other radius values.

EDIT:

If you assume that your arc will always be 1/4 of a circle or less, then you could use the Bezier curve for a 1/4 circle, and draw a portion of that arc by varying the range of the t parameter to a range less than t=0 -> t=1. You'd need to apply a rotation transform to your points to move them around the circle.

Comment: I don't even remotely understand this article. Also, I don't think he computing the control points, just the anchor points.

Comment: The OP says "...I have already computed the anchor points, how can I calculate the position of control point 1 and control point 2???" If you look at his illustration, the control points are the 2 inside points. Computing the anchor points is trivial using sine and cosine.

Comment: Are you talking about "The general formula of a cubic Bézier curve"

B(t) = (1-t)^3*P_0 + 3*(1-t)^2*t*P_1 + 3*(1-t)*t^2*P_2 + t^3*P_3, t in [0,1]

The first constraint implies that:
P_0 = (0,1), P_1 = (c,1), P_2 = (1,c), P_3 = (1,0)

The second constraint provides the value of c:
c = (4/3)*(sqrt(2) - 1)

If my first anchorPoint is 25,35, how do I use this formula to get anchorPoint 1's first control point (x,y)????

Comment: That article explains how to use 4 cubic Bezier curves to create a very close approximation of a full circle. As I said, I don't know how you'd come up with middle Bezier control points for an arbitrary arc of a circle. Other articles I've read indicate that a Bezier curve can create very good approximations of an arc up to 1/4 of a circle.

Comment: A link isn't an answer.  You should provide at least the final formulae here, in case the link stops working.

Comment: Also, a Bézier curve isn't (generally) parameterized by arc length, so finding the `t` for a given angle is not trivial.