# create a bezier curve from arc in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, bezier

I want to create a quadratic bezier curve from the two end points on a arc (x1, y1, x2, y2) and either the center point (cx,cy) or radius.

At one point, I thought that I could set the two control points to the intersection of the tangents, but that does not seem to work.

While an exact answer would be nice,  I can live with a reasonable approximation if required.   I have limited math skills but would appreciate simple pseudo code.  I have done a google search and some of the suggestions are too complex for me to follow.

The problem seems simple but I know it is not.

Comment: have you taken a look at d3.js?

Comment: Specifically, https://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier. The source can be https://www.jasondavies.com/animated-bezier/animated-bezier.js.

Comment: d3.js does not have math routines to convert arc's into quadratic splines.

Comment: My terminology was incorrect.  I should have asked for a cubic bezier curve.  
Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: the problem actually *is* relatively simple, but the problem is that you can't use cubic Bezier curves for any arc that's more than a little over a quarter circle. I've added an answer with the why.

Answer (score 2):

For a good approximation of a circle place the Bezier Quadratic control points at

```
var cp = (r * 4 * (Math.sqrt( 2 ) - 1)) / 3;
```

Where `r` is the radius of the circle at point `(x,y)`. `cp` is the distance along the tangent to put the control point.

```
ctx.moveTo(x-r,y)
ctx.quadCurve(x - r, y - pc, x + r, y - pc, x + r, y);
```

Will create a nice half a circle. Do the same for the bottom to get a full circle.

Comment: Thanks Blindman67,  

This may work for a half circle(180 degrees) but will it work for an arc of indeterminate angle?   My guess is that it would not.   I need something that works for any angle less than 180 degrees.

Comment: My terminology was incorrect,   I really need a cubic bezier curve from arc.
My mistake....

Answer (score 1):

There is no perfect mapping between arcs and Bezier curves due to the fact that a circle has parametric function:

```
fx(t) = cos(t)
fy(t) = sin(t)
```

which can only be represented in polynomial form as infinite sequences:

```
fx(t) = ∑(k=0,inf) x^(2k)   * (-1)^k / (2k)!
fy(t) = ∑(k=0,inf) x^(2k+1) * (-1)^k / (2k+1)!
```

Obviously, any finite degree Bezier curve will always be "off", although the higher the order, the less "off" we'll be. For a cubic curve we can approximate a quarter circle arc quite reasonably, although anything more than that and it'll look pretty obviously wrong: there's a detailed writeup on what a curve looks like given an arc of angle φ over on http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#circles_cubic, and it's worth reading over that section and then implementing its explanation (or "borrowing" the code from github, it's public domain code), as well as playing with the graphic to see exactly how wrong things get once you try to model more than a quarter circle.

Answer (score 0):

Quadratic Bezier curve has equation

```
B(t) = P0 * (1-t)^2+ 2 * P1 * t * (1-t) + P2 * t^2
```

For your case

```
P0 = (x1,y1)
P2 = (x2,y2)
```

To approximate an arc with Bezier, we can declare that middle point of curve must coincide with middle point of arc.

To find middle point of arc:
We have chord vector

```
V = (x2-x1, y2-y1)
```

perpendicular vector (not y sign change)

```
P = (y1-y2, x2-x1)
```

It's length

```
LenP = Sqrt((y1-y2)^2 + (x2-x1)^2)
```

unit perpendicular vector

```
uP = P/LenP = ( (y1-y2) / LenP, (x2-x1) / LenP)
```

Middle arc point

```
M = C + R * uP = (cx + R * (y1-y2) / LenP, cy + R * (x2-x1) / LenP)
```

Middle point of Bezier

```
B(1/2) = P0/4 + P1/2 + P2/4 = (x1/4 + px/2 + x2/4, y1/4 + py/2 + y2/4)
```

Now we can write equations

```
cx + R * (y1-y2) / LenP = x1/4 + px/2 + x2/4
cy + R * (x2-x1) / LenP = y1/4 + py/2 + y2/4
```

and find `px` and `py` - coordinates of control point.

Comment: Thanks MBo,   However it seems that you have given me a solution for a cubic bezier and I am using exclusively quadratic bezier curves.  P0, P1, P2, P3  where P1 and P2 are control points.  Did I misunderstand your solution?   Any suggestions on a quadratic bezier solution?

Comment: No, I gave solution for quadratic beziers. They have 3 control points - P0(starting), P1 and P2(ending).Sometimes only P1 is called 'control point' By the way, why do you want to use only quadratic ones?

Comment: I have code that creates bezier patches but uses only quadratic bezier.  P0 is starting point of the arc, P1 is a control point,  P2 is a control point and P3 is the end point of the arc.  The arc can traverse any angle less than 45 degrees in my case.   With only one control point (cubic bezier) I do not have sufficient control over the other splines I use and therefore decided to use quadratic beziers for everything.

Comment: I may be using incorrect terminology.  I have been assuming that a cubic had two end points and a control point and a quadratic bezier used two end points and two control points.

Comment: Yes, you was wrong. Quadratic curve - 3 points, cubic one - 4 points

Comment: Thanks MBo for pointing out my mistake in terminology.   Have you any idea how to solve my problem for a cubic bezier?  Or should I delete this topic and enter a new one?

Comment: Solution for arc defined by angles in Delphi is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764342/drawing-arc-with-bezier-curves/26774423#26774423. If you want direct solution for center/endpoint case, you'd better to make new question (this one might stay - it's still valid for quadratic case)