# How to draw a lowercase b with Quadratic Bezier Curve on HTML5 canvas

Tags: graphics, bezier

Wondering how to take the definition of a half circle arc and convert it into quadratic bezier curve, using the lowercase letter `b` as an example.

```js
var c = document.querySelector('canvas')
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
ctx.lineTo(0, 200)
ctx.lineTo(100, 200)
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(0, 100, 200, 0)
ctx.stroke()
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I don't see how to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34460561/169992) (which I think is using an outdated canvas API) to the current canvas API for quadratic bezier curves. Where the right side of the `b` is a half-circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var c = document.querySelector('canvas')
var ctx = c.getContext('2d')
ctx.width = ctx.height = 100
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.moveTo(0, 20)
ctx.lineTo(0, 40)
ctx.lineTo(10, 40)
half(10, 40, 5, 10, 30)
ctx.lineTo(0, 30)
ctx.stroke()

function half(sx, sy, radius, endx, endy, clock) {
  var x = sx + radius
  var y = sy - radius
  var cpx = sx + radius
  var cpy = sy
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cpx, cpy, x, y)
  var x = endx
  var y = endy
  var cpx = sx + radius
  var cpy = endy
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(cpx, cpy, x, y)
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```